# iOS pushing a View for second time.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In iOS 7 and XCode 5.

I have several views on a navigation view controller, using segues.

Some views are pushed by segue and others are pushed by code.
 View hierarchy:

```
  `View A -> View B -> View C -> View D`
```

Then
     `View D pops to View B.`

All this works without issues but then when I go to View B (after being popped by View D), View B cannot push again to View C. No error message, it just doesn't push.
The only way around it is to close the app and restart the app again until you pop D again.

Any suggestions? I can send code snippets if it helps.

**Edit:** code

Push from B to C (C is a tab bar view controller):

```
    MainTabBarViewController *mainTabBarVC = (MainTabBarViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainTabBarVC animated:YES];
```

Pop from D to B (D is a view within the Tab Bar VC):

```
int totalViews = [[self.parentViewController.navigationController viewControllers]count];
for (int i = 0; i < totalViews; i++)
{
    id obj = [[self.parentViewController.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[ContactAndDeliveryOptionsVC class]])
    {
        [self.parentViewController.navigationController popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably didn't dismiss C.

Comment: ? I'm confused. Why, how or where should I be dismissing C?

Comment: Can you post your code that performs the pushes and the pop back to B?

Comment: When you say "View D pops to View B" how are you creating the "pop"?

Comment: Yes, send code snippets. It would help.

Comment: @David I suspect it is a segue from D to B. Place your bets please :D

Comment: @Fogmeister we betting rep points? ill get in on that action

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin ooh! Where's the feature request button?!

Comment: @Fogmeister haha that's a great idea!

Comment: Hold on guys, I'll add the code in a second...

Comment: @Fogmeister ... I see your 5 points ... and I raise you a duplicate  question flag! boom!

Comment: @TooManyEduardos sorry, we hijacked the comments. Will get back to the point when you've edited :D

Comment: Hey, I looked for duplicated questions and I couldn't find anything with a similar issue or example

Comment: @TooManyEduardos have you looked into using unwind segues before? I think it might help in this situation.

Comment: No, I've actually never tried it. I'll play with that after lunch and see where I end up.
Thanx guys.

Comment: Did you check the values of `storyboard `, `self.navigationController` and `mainTabBarVC` ? *cough "bet" cough*

Comment: ???? what do you mean?

Comment: I can unwind, but I still can't go from B to C after returning to B